# Set Class Property From Multi-level JObject Property

Tags: c#, json.net

I have a class with properties like this:

```
    [JsonProperty("property_name")]
    public string PropertyName { get; internal set; }
```

and I then use `[JObject].ToObject<Class>()` to populate the properties on the class. This works fine in general, but some of the properties in the `JObject` are several levels down. For example, they would be accessed via `items.first_group.property`. However, if I try setting the `JsonProperty`'s `PropertyName` to that, e.g.

```
[JsonProperty("monkeyOne.name")]
```

it simply doesn't set the value. Am I just doing something wrong, or is it really not possible to do this? And if not, is there a reason or has it just not been implemented?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you say it is 'several levels down', it suggests there is no property 'monkeyOne.name'.

There may be a property 'monkeyOne' that is an object with a property 'name', but that is an entirely different thing.

ToObject can only be used if the overall structure of the JObject matches the class structure.

Comment: Yeah I know how to use it when it matches the class structure, but it seems like a bit of an oversight not to be able to go several levels in. (E.g. you *can* do `<object>.SelectToken("monkey_one.name"`). This is especially true because I might not *want* to create several "monkey" classes and have them eating up memory when all I really want is the name of each monkey.

Comment: The path to a token is an entirely different thing to a property name. If you believe it is an oversight, you can raise it here: https://github.com/JamesNK/Newtonsoft.Json/issues

Comment: Also, you can work directly with JObject (without deserialising to a matching C# class) by casting it as `dynamic`. You could then have code to map from JObject to your desired C# object. Some examples here: http://weblog.west-wind.com/posts/2012/Aug/30/Using-JSONNET-for-dynamic-JSON-parsing